django celery with redis, celery worker not receive any message
I have a django project with celery
Here is my proj/settings.py (just the celery parts)

    # -----CELERY
    CELERY_TIMEZONE = "Asia/jakarta"
    CELERY_BROKER_URL = "redis://localhost"
    CELERY_TASK_DEFAULT_QUEUE ='taibridge'
    CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE ='taibridge'
    CELERY_BROKER_CONNECTION_RETRY_ON_STARTUP = True
    # ---EOF-CELERY

and here is my proj/celery.py
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'main.settings')
app = Celery('main')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')



Running the worker from console, I Got
[2024-05-16 06:09:54,926: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Preparing bootsteps.
[2024-05-16 06:09:54,928: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Building graph...
[2024-05-16 06:09:54,928: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: New boot order: {Beat, Timer, Hub, Pool, Autoscaler, StateDB, Consumer}
[2024-05-16 06:09:54,933: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Preparing bootsteps.
[2024-05-16 06:09:54,933: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Building graph...
[2024-05-16 06:09:54,941: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: New boot order: {Connection, Events, Mingle, Gossip, Heart, Agent, Tasks, Control, event loop}
 
 -------------- celery@taiga-project v5.4.0 (opalescent)
--- ***** ----- 
-- ******* ---- Linux-5.15.0-60-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.35 2024-05-16 06:09:54
- *** --- * --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         main:0x7fd4d824ab00
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://localhost:6379//
- ** ---------- .> results:     disabled://
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 8 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> taibridge        exchange=taibridge(direct) key=taibridge
                

[tasks]
  . celery.accumulate
  . celery.backend_cleanup
  . celery.chain
  . celery.chord
  . celery.chord_unlock
  . celery.chunks
  . celery.group
  . celery.map
  . celery.starmap
  . taibridge.tasks.post_to_taiga

[2024-05-16 06:09:54,948: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Starting Hub
[2024-05-16 06:09:54,948: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2024-05-16 06:09:54,949: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Starting Pool
[2024-05-16 06:09:55,382: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2024-05-16 06:09:55,383: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Starting Consumer
[2024-05-16 06:09:55,384: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Connection
[2024-05-16 06:09:55,393: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://localhost:6379//
[2024-05-16 06:09:55,393: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2024-05-16 06:09:55,393: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Events
[2024-05-16 06:09:55,396: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2024-05-16 06:09:55,396: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Mingle
[2024-05-16 06:09:55,396: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2024-05-16 06:09:56,406: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2024-05-16 06:09:56,406: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2024-05-16 06:09:56,406: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Gossip
[2024-05-16 06:09:56,410: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2024-05-16 06:09:56,410: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Heart
[2024-05-16 06:09:56,412: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2024-05-16 06:09:56,412: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Tasks
[2024-05-16 06:09:56,416: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2024-05-16 06:09:56,416: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Control
[2024-05-16 06:09:56,420: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2024-05-16 06:09:56,420: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting event loop
[2024-05-16 06:09:56,420: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Hub.register Pool...
[2024-05-16 06:09:56,421: INFO/MainProcess] celery@taiga-project ready.
[2024-05-16 06:09:56,421: DEBUG/MainProcess] basic.qos: prefetch_count->32


here is my taibridge/tasks.py
import logging, traceback
import json

from celery import shared_task
from django.conf import settings
from taibridge.models import Post, PostStatus
from taibridge.taiga_tools import TaigaTools

logger = logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

taiga_tools = TaigaTools()

@shared_task
def post_to_taiga(post_id,trial:int=0):
    try :
        postObj = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
    except Post.DoesNotExist as e:
        return
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(traceback.format_exc())
        return

    project_name = postObj.caller.scrum.name

    sprint_prefix = postObj.caller.scrum.sprint_prefix
    sprint_suffix = postObj.received_at.strftime('%b %Y')
    sprint_name = f'{sprint_prefix} {sprint_suffix}'

    # THIS IS SUCK !!!
    # Find some way to make it DYNAMIC !!!!!
    us_subject = 'Alert'

    ts_text = postObj.received_at.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    task_subject = f'by {postObj.caller.name} at {ts_text}'
    task_description = postObj.message

    try :
        task_description = json.loads(task_description)
        task_description = json.dumps(task_description, indent='\t')
    except Exception:
        pass

    posted = False
    status = None
    try :
        taiga_tools.create_task(subject=task_subject, description=task_description,
            user_story=us_subject, sprint=sprint_name, project=project_name)
        status = "POSTED"
    except Exception as e:
        logger.warn(traceback.format_exc())
        countdown = trial+2
        trial += 1
        try :
            post_to_taiga.apply_async((post_id, trial), countdown=countdown)
            status = f'REQUEUED: {trial}'
        except Exception as e:
            err = traceback.format_exc()
            status = err
            logger.error(err)
    
    new_status = PostStatus()
    new_status.post = postObj
    new_status.status = status
    new_status.save()


I try to send some task via django shell
(venv) bino@taiga-project:~/TaiBridge$ ./manage.py shell
Python 3.10.12 (main, Nov 20 2023, 15:14:05) [GCC 11.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from taibridge.tasks import post_to_taiga
>>> post_to_taiga.delay("XYZ")
<AsyncResult: f7830aae-2f80-4207-a657-7e08f9715784>
>>> post_to_taiga.delay("XYZ")
<AsyncResult: a388126c-1ace-4c5a-a805-f7ba3b5edd90>
>>> 


But I dont see anythong happend at my celery terminal.
Looks like my celery didn't recevive any task/message
Kindly please tell me what to check or what todo to fix this problem.
